# Does string::capacity/reserve() count terminating null?

Tags: c++, stdstring, std

It's not obvious from cppref's description on [`capacity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity) and [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) whether terminating null character is counted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard [states that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.string#4):

> In all cases, `size() <= capacity()`.

And `size()` does not include the terminating null.

Since it is possible that `size()` equals `capacity()`, in that case it would mean that `capacity()` also does not count the terminating null.

Note that in C++11 and later, `mystring.c_str()` is equivalent to `mystring.data()` is equivalent to `&mystring[0]`, and `mystring[mystring.size()]` is guaranteed to be `'\0'`.

Check this [**Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pGlMqapTcKJdUm70).

Comment: The fact that `capacity()` can be equal to `size()` clearly allows the possibility for `capacity()` to not include the space required for a terminating null character.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is non-committal about that. The null character is not even mentioned in the [documentation of `basic_string`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.string).

In many of the member functions' documentation, it is mentioned that:

> capacity() a value at least as large as size()

However, there is nothing that says `capacity()` must be larger than `size()` to be able to hold the null character.

Here's an example program that shows that neither `resize()` nor `capacity()` know anything about terminating null characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string s1(10, 'a');
   std::cout << "size: " << s1.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "capacity: " << s1.capacity() << std::endl;

   std::string s2;
   s2.resize(5);
   s2[0] = 'a';
   s2[1] = 'b';
   s2[2] = 'c';
   s2[3] = 'd';
   s2[4] = 'e';
   std::cout << "size: " << s2.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "capacity: " << s2.capacity() << std::endl;

   std::string s3("abcd");
   std::cout << "size: " << s3.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "capacity: " << s3.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

Output with `g++ --std=c++14` on my laptop:

```
size: 10
capacity: 10
size: 5
capacity: 5
size: 4
capacity: 4
```